# Merging 2 streams using common field

Tags: akka, streaming

Is there a known pattern for merging 2 streams with same value in a specific field into one in Akka?

For example one stream is:
`id, first_name`

The other one is: `id, last_name`

And it is needed to have `id, first_name, last_name` in the output, once the `id` matches in both streams.

Obviously 2 streams can be slightly (within some tolerable timeframe) out of sync.